# Alternatives to stacked iron plates for electric motor cores?

Tags: motor, materials

I took apart a brushless motor to find a core made of stacked iron plates. This material is rather dense and heavy for a motor made for aviation. 
What lighter, less dense material can a motor core be made of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lightest stator core material is nothing - literally.

In a coreless ironless motor the stator coils are wound around a non-metallic frame, glued to a surface, or even suspended in mid-air with the coils themselves forming the motor frame.

The motor below weighs 28g and produces 83W at 60000rpm (100W input power, 83% efficiency). The frame is made of plastic, and the rotor is a cylindrical Neodymium magnet. The only 'iron' in this motor is the shaft.

[image]

Here's a tiny home-made motor which has a 0.5mm diameter rotor. The shaft and bearings are held in place by the windings. The black rectangle glued on top is an [A1442](http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/A1442-Datasheet.ashx) BLDC controller IC with built-in Hall sensor.

[image]

Comment: Would you think it's possible to make one of these that is on the scale of about 1 HP output??